# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.project.R$navigation"

Tags: android, kotlin

Im having a a problem with a R.navigation class that is no loading into my project that is used by a SDK im assign to implement. It appears on the R.txt and i can call it via and import statement, but always gives a "Didn't find error".

R.txt

````
int navigation nav_graph_other_docs 0x7f100001
int navigation nav_graph_otp 0x7f100002
int navigation nav_graph_resume 0x7f100003
int navigation navigation_empty 0x7f100004
int navigation navigation_fad_sdk_face 0x7f100005
int navigation sdkfad_nav_graph 0x7f100006 ```
````

[image: Import of class R.navigation]

[image: Error in log]

If anyone has bumped into this error before, helped would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of breaking my head with this i found that i had to comment this line in gradle.properties and that got rid of the error.

`android.nonTransitiveRClass=true`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `com.na_at.demo.mobilecard` and `com.otcperu.mobilecardmx` are different packages. Maybe you were editing the right resource but in the wrong package...

I'd make this a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.